# css (this) element and input background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code and i want input field background color red not working..:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".abc").focus(function(){
        $(this).attr('background', 'red');
        $("label").text('Tekstas cia').fadeOut(2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="male">Last name:</label>
<input class="abc" type="text" name="LastName" value=""><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `attr` to `css`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".abc").focus(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        $("label").text('Tekstas cia').fadeOut(2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="male">Last name:</label>
<input class="abc" type="text" name="LastName" value=""><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `css()` instead of `attr()` and `background-color` instead of `background`

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
    $(".abc").focus(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        $("label").text('Tekstas cia').fadeOut(2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="male">Last name:</label>
<input class="abc" type="text" name="LastName" value=""><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid at all `JS/Jquery` and use only `CSS` at least to apply the colour on `focus` event

```
.abc:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

As a good practice keep always your style out of the script 
for the sake of maintainability of the code